# program using hibernate does not terminate

Tags: java, hibernate

I created a program using Hibernate.

The program reaches the main function end, nevertheless the program is running.

I wonder if it happens when `SessionFactory` is configured using Hibernate Version 4.x.

Is the way to configure wrong?

---

**manual1_1_first_hibernate_apps.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    args[0] ="list";
    if (args.length <= 0) {
        System.err.println("argement was not given");
        return;
    }

    manual1_1_first_hibernate_apps mgr = new manual1_1_first_hibernate_apps();

    if (args[0].equals("store")) {
        mgr.createAndStoreEvent("My Event", new Date());
    }
    else if (args[0].equals("list")) {
        mgr.<Event>listEvents().stream()
            .map(e -> "Event: " + e.getTitle() + " Time: " + e.getDate())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    Util.getSessionFactory().close();
}

private <T> List<T> listEvents() {
    Session session = Util.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<T> events = Util.autoCast(session.createQuery("from Event").list());
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return events;
}
```

**Util.java**

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

/**
 * build a SessionFactory
 */
static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml

        // hibernate version lower than 4.x are as follows
        // # it successful termination. but buildSessionFactory method is deprecated.
        // sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        // version 4.3 and later
        // # it does not terminate. I manually terminated.
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = 
                new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

/**
 * @return built SessionFactory
 */
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

---

The following console log snippets when program terminate and use buildSessionFactory method.

```
2 08, 2014 8:42:25 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:derby:D:\Java\jdk1.7.0_03(x86)\db\bin\testdb]
```

but if do not use deprecated buildSessionFactory method and terminated(program is running), the above two lines do not appear.

ENVIRONMENT:

```
 Hibernate 4.3.1
 DERBY
 JRE 1.8
 IntelliJ IDEA 13
```

Comment: a "kill -3" on the process might be handy

Comment: thanks. I do not use kill command, but I noticed that see the thread dump to see your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maybe, I solved this problem.

I saw the thread dump after Util.getSessionFactory().close() called, a thread named  "pool-2-thread-1" state was TIMED_WAITING (parking).

The following snippets dump

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.0-b69 mixed mode):

"DestroyJavaVM" #16 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000020b9000 nid=0x3684 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"pool-2-thread-1" #15 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001bc27000 nid=0x3f0 waiting on condition [0x000000001ce6f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000080be30a0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

"derby.rawStoreDaemon" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001b059000 nid=0xa3c in Object.wait() [0x000000001ba1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000805f6190> (a org.apache.derby.impl.services.daemon.BasicDaemon)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.daemon.BasicDaemon.rest(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000805f6190> (a org.apache.derby.impl.services.daemon.BasicDaemon)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.daemon.BasicDaemon.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

"Timer-0" #13 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001b08e800 nid=0x2160 in Object.wait() [0x000000001b6af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000080608118> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
    - locked <0x0000000080608118> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

I thought the cause is thread named "pool-2-thread-1" that created by  buildSessionFactory method.

As a result of comparing the two buildSessionFactory method, I noticed that ServiceRegistry resources has not released.

Program successfully terminated by releasing it.

The following code, I adding.

Util.java

```
configuration.setSessionFactoryObserver(
        new SessionFactoryObserver() {
            @Override
            public void sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactory factory) {}
            @Override
            public void sessionFactoryClosed(SessionFactory factory) {
                ((StandardServiceRegistryImpl) serviceRegistry).destroy();
            }
        }
);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 49):

I met this problem also today, and I found the solution is, in the end of your main method (or thread), you should close your Session Factory, like:

```
sessionFactory.close();
```

And then, your program will terminate normally.

If You use JavaFX 8 in main method add:

```
@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    sessionFactory.close();
}
```

This method will close session factory and destroy thread on program exit.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem today, but I found another similar solution:

I inserted at the end of my code the following line:

```
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);
```

And Ta-dah! the program ends.

Answer (score 7):

Same problem in 4.3.4.Final.

Now after adding following code, the problem is gone.

```
public class Service {
private SessionFactory factory;
private ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

public void initialize() throws Exception{

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("com/jeecourse/config/hibernate.cfg.xml");

    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).build();

    factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

}

public void close() throws Exception{
    if(serviceRegistry!= null) {
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);
    }
}
```

.....

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Hibernate 4.3.1 introduced a bug. I create the connection in my application with:

```
EntityManagerFactory connection = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(...)
```

but even if the `createEntityManagerFactory` method fails with an exception, the service registry remains open. However, as you could see from the above code, I cannot terminate my application because as the method didn't succeed the variable `connection` wasn't assigned (it is *null*), so I cannot call `connection.close()` that would destroy the service registry. It seems that this is really a bug, because how will I be able to release resources without resorting to a hack, like using specific Hibernate APIs from a JPA application?

Answer (score 4):

I met this problem also today, and I found that the solution like:

```
sessionFactory.close();
```

will work if you have

```
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using hibenate 5.2.12 with sqlite 3.20.1, managing the connection manually. In my case the problem was that not only the entity manager had to be closed but also the entity manager factory.

With these attributes:

```
EntityManager entityManager;
EntityTransaction entityTransaction;
```

This snippet is used when opening the DB and starting a transaction:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, map);
entityManager = emf.createEntityManager(map);
entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
entityTransaction.begin();
```

This snipped is used to commit the transaction and close the DB:

```
entityTransaction.commit();
if ( entityManager.isOpen() ) {
    entityManager.close();
}
EntityManagerFactory emf = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
if ( emf.isOpen() ) {
    emf.close();
}
```

Now with `emf.close();` my application terminates as is should be.

Answer (score 1):

I have just had the same problem. I was using Hibernate 4.1.1 and everything was working fine. Today I upgraded to Hibernate 4.3.1 and suddenly my application didn't terminate anymore. I investigated a little further and noticed that version 4.1.1 didn't have any problem with an open EntityManagerFactory. That's why my application always terminated. That's not the case with version 4.3.1 anymore. So I checked my application and made sure that the EntityManagerFactory was closed at the end (indeed I was not really closing it). Problem solved to me. Are you really sure there's nothing left open in your application? Hope this helps.

Marcos

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, the solution is so simple , you have to add this property to configuration's file

```
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">0</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is for Hibernate 4.3+ version, and I use it in my way.

A example of Spring Annotation configured with Hibernate:

```
//Using AutoCloseable 1.7 feature here to close context and 
//suppress warning Resource leak: 'context' is never closed
//Creating AutoClosebale AbstractApplicationContext Object context
try (AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringAppConfig.class)) {

    SnacksMenu snacks = context.getBean(SnacksMenu.class);
    System.out.println(snacks.toString());

    //Creating AutoClosebale SessionFactory Object factory
    try (SessionFactory factory = getStandardServiceEnabledSessionFactory()){

        //Creating AutoClosebale Session Object session
        try (Session session = factory.openSession()) {

            SessionCounter.analysisSession(session);
            System.out.println("1: Opened Sessions under factory : " + SessionCounter.getOpenSessionsCount());

            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            session.persist(snacks);
            transaction.commit();

            System.out.println(session.isConnected());
        }//Session Object session resource auto closed

    }//SessionFactory Object factory resource auto closed

    System.out.println("2: Opened Sessions under factory : " + SessionCounter.getOpenSessionsCount());

}//AbstractApplicationContext Object context resource auto closed
```

Answer (score 0):

We have multiple connections to database.

```
class ConnectionProviderFactory implements DataBaseConnectionProvider {

private EnumMap<SystemInstance, Properties> connectionsConfigs = new EnumMap<>(SystemInstance.class);
private Map<SystemInstance, EntityManager> entityManagers = new HashMap<>();
private Map<SystemInstance, ConnectionPerSystemInstance> connections = new HashMap<>();


@Getter
private static class ConnectionPerSystemInstance {

    private String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private final SystemInstance systemInstance;

    private ConnectionPerSystemInstance(final SessionFactory sessionFactory, SystemInstance systemInstance){
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        this.systemInstance = systemInstance;
    }

    static ConnectionPerSystemInstance createConnection(Properties properties, SystemInstance systemInstance) {
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        registryBuilder.applySettings(toMap(properties));
        StandardServiceRegistry registry = registryBuilder.build();
        MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);
        Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        return new ConnectionPerSystemInstance(sessionFactory, systemInstance);
    }

    private static Map<String, String> toMap(Properties properties) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (String name : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
            map.put(name, properties.getProperty(name));
        }
        return map;
    }

    EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        if(sessionFactory == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Connection not initialized!");
        }
        return sessionFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    void close() {
        if(sessionFactory == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Connection not initialized!");
        }
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        final ConnectionPerSystemInstance that = (ConnectionPerSystemInstance) o;

        return uuid.equals(that.uuid);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return uuid.hashCode();
    }
}

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    String testQuery = "select sysdate from dual";

    EntityManager e1TEST = connect(SystemInstance.TEST);

    EntityManager e1PROD = connect(SystemInstance.PROD);

    log.info("" + e1TEST.createNativeQuery(testQuery).getSingleResult());
    log.info("" + e1PROD.createNativeQuery(testQuery).getSingleResult());
}

@PreDestroy
private void clean() {
    entityManagers.forEach((key, value) -> value.close());
    connections.forEach((systemInstance, connectionPerSystemInstance) -> {
        connectionPerSystemInstance.close();
    });
}

@Override
public EntityManager connect(final SystemInstance systemInstance) {

    if (Optional.ofNullable(entityManagers.get(systemInstance)).isPresent()) {
        entityManagers.get(systemInstance);
    }

    Properties properties = loadConnectionProperties(systemInstance);
    ConnectionPerSystemInstance connection = ConnectionPerSystemInstance.createConnection(properties, systemInstance);
    connections.put(systemInstance, connection);
    entityManagers.put(systemInstance, connection.getEntityManager());

    return entityManagers.get(systemInstance);
}

@Override
public void closeAllConnection() {
    clean();
}

private Properties loadConnectionProperties(SystemInstance systemInstance) {

    if (Optional.ofNullable(connectionsConfigs.get(systemInstance)).isPresent()) {
        return connectionsConfigs.get(systemInstance);
    }

    return tryLoadConnectionProperties(systemInstance);
}

private Properties tryLoadConnectionProperties(final SystemInstance systemInstance) {
    final String nameOfPropertyFile = getNameOfPropertyFile(systemInstance);
    ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource(nameOfPropertyFile);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(classPathResource.getInputStream());
        addAdditionalConnectionSettings(properties);
        connectionsConfigs.put(systemInstance, properties);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());                                                                             //TODO chanfe exception
    }
    return properties;
}

private String getNameOfPropertyFile(SystemInstance systemInstance) {
    if (systemInstance == SystemInstance.TEST)
        return "db/db-test.properties";
    if (systemInstance == SystemInstance.PROD)
        return "db/db-prod.properties";
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect configuration");
}

private void addAdditionalConnectionSettings(Properties properties) {
    properties.putIfAbsent("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    properties.putIfAbsent("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "0");
}
```

}

In this example we have multiple databases so we can easily close all connections.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, the reason is we need to close the resources properly.
try closing the resources in finally block

```html
try{
   Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
   sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();;
   session = sessionFactory.openSession();
   transaction = session.beginTransaction();
   session.save(person);
   transaction.commit();
   }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Exception occured. "+e.getMessage());
   }finally{
    if(session.isOpen()){
     System.out.println("Closing session");
     session.close();
    }
    if(!sessionFactory.isClosed()){
     System.out.println("Closing SessionFactory");
     sessionFactory.close();
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the same SessionFactory instance you are dealing with through out the program. i.e. The program must terminate if you are closing the same SessionFactory that you built and opened the Session in the program. The source code in the question part doesn't guaranty this and hence the trouble.

Please have a look at the following simple and straight forward solution,

```
//your class definition
public static void main(String args[]) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction().begin();
        session.save(yourEntity);
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("com/srees/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }
//your class def ends here
```