# Hibernate program not terminating

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I wrote a simple Hibernate program, and it seems to be working fine, the data gets loaded into the DB, table gets created. However the program doesn't terminate after commit() is called.

Here is the piece of code that i am using:

```
    SessionFactory sessionFactory= new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(model);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

I am using MySQL as DB for this, running the program in eclipse.

Please suggest as to what might be wrong here.

Thanks,
Vipin

Comment: Please elaborate. From your post one can assume that your think that commit is equal to program terminating. Whereas it's not true it's just finish transaction. What happens next depends on what code is next.

Comment: In main(), commit() is last method call, hence if commit() is successful, then i believe it should exit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [program using hibernate does not terminate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645516/program-using-hibernate-does-not-terminate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sessionFactory.close();
```

Is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing this(bellow commit):

```
session.close();
```

Final Code:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory= new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(model);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close(); //Here
```

Comment: I tried session.close() however still the program doesn't terminate. In fact, in mysql i tried to commit manually to check if commit isn't working from java, that still didn't help either :-(

Comment: Can you post your hibernate.cfg.xml file...the line about hibernate.connection.release_mode