# Simple Hibernate program not terminating... eclipse bug or hibernate issue?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, orm

I am just trying to learn Hibernate. So I wrote a small program to save user details (userid, username). I am using following: -

> Java - 1.7 Eclipse - Mars Hibernate - 4.3.1 final Database - Oracle
>   10g XE

After I execute the program the console continues to show that the program is still executing and has not terminated.

What could be the issue ... is it hibernate problem or eclipse bug ?
It even prints the last statement in the program.

[image: Screenshot of my simple program]

Comment: Try this line to see if the program terminates :  StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);

Comment: Thanks @RamachandranGA ... yes what you suggested helped. Cheers ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad, i found the solution as tip from another question posted for hibernate in SO.

```
serviceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);
```

Made the program end. 
Nothing else Helped... even session.close() or sessionFactory.close() does not help.

The link that proved helpful is as follows: -
[program using hibernate does not terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645516/program-using-hibernate-does-not-terminate)